# Styling button in javaFX using CSS

Tags: css, intellij-idea, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have a problem with styling button in javaFX using CSS.
I use Intellij Idea IDE.
I have CSS.css file :

```
#Button {
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 8;
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #a34313 0%, #903b12 100%),
        #9d4024,
        #d86e3a,
        radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #d86e3a, #c54e2c);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
}
#Button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #a34313 0%, #903b12 100%),
        #9d4024,
        #d86e3a,
        radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #ea7f4b, #c54e2c);
}
#Button:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
#Button Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , #a30000 , 0,0,0,2 );
}
```

sample.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="271.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button id="Button" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" stylesheets="@../../../../Desktop/CSS.css" text="MyButtonStyle" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this is the main class : 
package sample;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

in javaFX Scene builder the button style is changed :

[image]

But when I compile my code the button get the default CSS style :
[image]

Why when I compile my code the button style dosen't change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve my problem , I changed the directory of .css file from Desktop to `src\sample` using JavaFX Scene Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with your css file. Main reason is that the CSS.css file is not linked properly with your project so  Now put the CSS.css file in the directory of your project and try again.
You can learn more at [JavaFX CSS BUtton](http://javafxtuts.com/javafx-button-css/)

Answer (score 0):

This solve my issue

```
.button {
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 8;
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #9b9d9e 0%, #7a7c7d 100%),
            #7a7c7d,
            #9b9d9e,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #7a7c7d, #9b9d9e);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.3em;
}
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #9b9d9e 0%, #7a7c7d 100%),
            #7a7c7d,
            #9b9d9e,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #9b9d9e, #7a7c7d);
}
.button:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
.button Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , #a30000 , 0,0,0,2 );
}
```

**Project structure**

[image]

**Main class**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("IeltsDatabaseAutomation.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("IELTS Speaking database automation");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```